# Im having an issue with the jquery autocomplete select method

Tags: javascript, jquery

My current code is

```
$(".Commodities").autocomplete({
source: function (request, response) {
    $.getJSON('url',  function (data) {
            var comms = $.map(data, function (el) {
                 return {
                     label: el.desc,
                     value: el.desc
                     
                 };
             
             });
               response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(comms, request.term));
            
         })   
     },
      minLength: 2,
          select: function( event, ui,el ) {
        $('#commcd').val(ui.item.code);
      
        }
         
});
```

I'm not really familiar with the `ui.item` part of the code but I'm assuming it's pulling from the mapped out json. I'm sure that my formatting is off somewhere and I'm assuming its how I used the `ui.item` property. I'm at a loss but it would be a huge help if anyone could shed a light on this the last step I need to finish this is just passing that extra value to an input field.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It would be best to provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example The issue you are facing is that `code` does not exist as an element of the object. You would want to use `ui.item.label` or `ui.item.value` depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following.

```
$(".Commodities").autocomplete({
  source: function (request, response) {
    $.getJSON('url?term=' + request.term, function (data) {
      var comms = $.map(data, function (el) {
        return {
          label: el.desc,
          value: el.desc,
          code: el.code
        };     
      });
      response(comms);      
    })   
  },
  minLength: 2,
  select: function(event, ui) {
    $('#commcd').val(ui.item.code);
    return false;
  } 
});
```

If your URL is an API, it should be able to accept a `term` or `query` to help reduce the results. It is always better to do this server-side if possible. Otherwise, you can filter the results as you did.

```
response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(comms, request.term));
```

Comment: That worked very well thank you. Could I ask why my past response line was less efficient? I'm still new to using this method and clarity would definitely help.

Comment: @Justkil you had created an Object with two elements: `{ label, value }`. Later in the `select` callback, you called a third element `code` that didn't exist.

Comment: I meant with the response filter. I understand where I didnt define the object I was referencing.